# How to design column based css grid layout dynamically as like this screenshot?

Tags: css, layout, grid

[here is the screenshot , see the elements height is dynamic , based on inner content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZoUK.png)

Comment: A screenshot is not a question. Can you provide some more information and maybe a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for is `masonry grid`.

If you may have a closer look, - here are some information:
https://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

But head up: it is an actual technique. So have an additional look to https://caniuse.com/ if you would like to use it for a project.